# How to increment the values

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

i have value like this '00100-01999' i need to increment this one as '00100,00101,......01999'

i have written the script like this

```
DECLARE @vc_value VARCHAR(20),
    @min VARCHAR(10),
    @Max VARCHAR(10),
    @String VARCHAR(10),
    @Start BIGINT,
    @End BIGINT
CREATE TABLE #1 (ID VARCHAR(20))
SET @vc_value = '00100-01999'

SET @min = SUBSTRING(@vc_value, 1, CHARINDEX('-', @vc_value) - 1)

SET @Max = SUBSTRING(@vc_value, CHARINDEX('-', @vc_value) + 1, LEN(@vc_value))
SELECT @min,@max

WHILE CAST(@min AS INT) <= CAST(@Max AS INT)
BEGIN

    INSERT INTO #1
    SELECT CAST(@min AS VARCHAR(10))
    SET @min = @min + 1

    SELECT @min
END

SELECT * FROM #1
```

but i am getting result as 100,101,....1999

i need to get like '00100,00101,......01999'

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the required number of leading zeros. Try this:

```
WHILE CAST(@min AS INT) <= CAST(@Max AS INT)
BEGIN

    INSERT INTO #1
    SELECT RIGHT('00000'+ CAST(@min AS VARCHAR(10)),5)
    SET @min = @min + 1

    SELECT @min
END
```

This will append `'00000'` to 100,101,....1999, giving you `'00000100'` as a string, then it takes the last 5 characters from that string.

Comment: yeah i implemented that code but need to modify in WHILE statement need to remove cast